# bootstrap not connect to the angular 6?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Configure `angular.json`:

```
"styles": [
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"styles.scss"
]
```

Import directly in `src/style.css`:

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

after this i got this error:

> ERROR in multi ./styles/bootstrap-4/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   ./src/styles.css Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '/Users/kobi.ktk/Documents/3yr/UI/a4app/styles/bootstrap-4/css/bootstrap.min.css'
>   in '/Users/kobi.ktk/Documents/3yr/UI/a4app'

Comment: whild guess, should it be? @import '~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

Comment: Remove tilt from style.css

Comment: ya ,already import  @Hooman

Comment: Try adding CDN. If it works then its an path issue. @import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';

Comment: Sorry , i didn't get u post .can explain clearly ?@Sanoj_V

Comment: Try using this `@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` instead of `@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` this.

Comment: If you're adding it to the `styles` block in the `angular.json` then direct import is not required.

Comment: it's better to import all your styles in src/style.css since it’s been declared in angular.json already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In angular 6 you have to do it as bellow:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

Then **only** in `src/style.css` file add:

```
@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

In angular 6 you don't have to add script to `angular.json` file

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: But, why is this change? Do provide view in case of any.