# Bootstrap 4 button spacing in Angular 2 CLI project

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I struggle to understand why the spacing between Bootstrap buttons inside the Angular 2 CLI project is failing.

I've created a brand new Angular 2 CLI app as described here: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Added Bootstrap 4.1.3 to the **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "my-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Added the Bootstrap styling to the **angular.json** file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-test": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-test",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-test:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-test:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-test:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "my-test-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my-test:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-test:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-test"
}
```

Finally, I copied the buttons from the Bootstrap documentation as described here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/ - one inside the Angular App component and one outside the scope of the app directly in the index.html file.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyTest</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<h2 class="text-danger">Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>

<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark</button>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

As you can see on the image below - the buttons outside the Angular App maintains the spacing between the buttons as they should appear according the official Bootstrap page - while the one inside the Angular App does not have spacing between the buttons. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? The styling of the elements appears to be the exact same when I inspect/compare them in the browser.

[image: Angular CLI App with two button rows]

*FYI: I'm well aware of how to solve this issue by adding margin to the buttons - I'm simply trying to understand why this is happening.*

Comment: add bootstrap to you project as below:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559810/bootstrap-not-connect-to-the-angular-6/50559906#50559906

Comment: Already tried this - still same behavior.

Comment: Can you see in your F12 what happen to margin/padding?

Comment: BTW it better to use bootstrap in angular as I show you

Comment: If you inspect the buttons on the bootstrap page here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/ you can see that there originally are no margins on the buttons.

Comment: Why is it better to use bootstrap the way you showed?

Comment: That's padding not margin...

Comment: sorry you right but wait please I will find..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is due to the [preserveWhitespaces](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preserveWhitespaces) option which is false by default and nothing to do with bootstrap. You can enable it by the setting that option to true as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],  
  preserveWhitespaces: true
})
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cabspk

Comment: Finally! It was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

According [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLu18aho/) bootstrap was installed successfully

All you need is to use [`bootstrap 4 spacing`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

See example:(I use `mb-1` to the first wrap div what means `margin-bottom` )

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="mb-1">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark</button> 
  </div>
 <div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark</button> 
 </div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help :)