# carousel is not working inside mat-tab in Angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

I am trying to have carousel in mat-tab ,In my application I have 3 tabs  (mat-tab-group).I want to have a carousel inside all tabs.

But in my case carousel is working inside the first  tab only the 2nd and 3rd tab's  carousel are not working .(it's not automatically switch the images after the specific time ).

app.component.html

```
 <div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px">
          <mat-tab-group>
            <mat-tab label="Mobile">
              <div style="padding-top: 25px" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 ProductImg" src="{{activeMobileProduct.img}}" alt="{{activeMobileProduct.alt}}">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let mobile of mobileProducts">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 ProductImg" src="{{mobile.img}}" alt="{{mobile.alt}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </mat-tab> //This part is working

            <mat-tab label="Web">
              <div style="padding-top: 25px" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 ProductImg" src="{{activeWebProduct.img}}" alt="{{activeWebProduct.alt}}">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let web of webProducts">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 ProductImg" src="{{web.img}}" alt="{{web.alt}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </mat-tab> //It's not working as I mentioned above.

            <mat-tab label="Windows">

            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Clients"> Clients </mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>
        </div>
```

stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-active-3haqea?file=app/tabs-template-label-example.html

Can anyone give me the solution for this issue.

Comment: please put your code in blitz,fork and post link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-active

Comment: please see the stackblitz update @לבנימלכה

Comment: in your link both of them do not work

Comment: Yes it’s not working in both @לבנימלכה

Comment: do you use `carousel` of bootstrap?

Comment: Yes bootstrap carousel @לבנימלכה

Comment: do you install bootsrap to your project:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559810/bootstrap-not-connect-to-the-angular-6/50559906#50559906

Comment: yes I have included it @לבנימלכה please check the index.html file

Comment: best why to install as in my answer

Comment: Yes I have included it in my real project as you mentioned but still the same issue