# Angular7 component is not shown correctly (and toggle does not work)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular7

I've been trying for hours to understand what's happening here, but I didn't manage to understand. 
I've written the html body for a navigation bar, which is shown below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class = "container-fluid">

    <div class = "navbar-header">
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Segmentation Folks</a>
</div>

<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">
  <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href ="#">Home</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href ="#">About</a></li>   
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href ="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href ="#">Sign in</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href ="#">Sign up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

When I open the html file from my computer, [they all seem to be as I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFsXC.png)

But when I copied the html body to be an Angular component, [the result is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt6M0.png). In addition the toggle button when the screen is small does not work, while in html it works.

Do you know why this happens? Thank you!

**EDIT!**
I have installed the bootstrap 3.3.6 and I have removed the scripts and link from this html. Then I included in the index.html below the  the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

It seems that now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Instead use links use [cli to install bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559810/bootstrap-not-connect-to-the-angular-6/50559906#50559906) .

But to install **3.3.6** use this command:

```
npm install bootstrap@3.3.6
```

[Here is working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-6qbypa?file=src/styles.css)

**EDIT MAKE COLLAPSE WORK WITH ANGULAR**

add in ts

```
collapsed:boolean=true;
```

html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class = "container-fluid">

<div class = "navbar-header">
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse" (click)="collapsed = !collapsed;">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Segmentation Folks</a>
</div>

<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse" [ngClass]="{'collapse': collapsed, 'navbar-collapse': true}">
  <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href ="#">Home</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href ="#">About</a></li>   
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href ="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href ="#">Sign in</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href ="#">Sign up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: it seems that the design is ok now, but the toggle button still does not work. any idea for this?