# Angular Bootstrap 4 Navbar won't toggle and problems with navbar-dark

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I have a small screen width and I'm trying to click the hamburger to toggle the navigation - nothing happens. I've already tried to solve the problem with already asked questions, but I haven't been able to find my error.
 Additionally as soon as I remove `navbar-dark` the hamburger vanishes - having this class added to the object again, changes the color of the navbar to white, which I don't want it to.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-2">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="collapse justify-content-end navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book Me</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Angular.json:**

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
```

**Package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.8.5",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^4.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

Comment: first of all install bootstrap to angular as here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559810/bootstrap-not-connect-to-the-angular-6/50559906#50559906

Comment: @לבנימלכה Adding the import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; brings won't find the document. When I add /node_modules in front of it, WebStorm is able to find the doc, but angular says that there's no such file.

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues:

1. install bootstrap to angular 6+ [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559810/bootstrap-not-connect-to-the-angular-6/50559906#50559906)
2. Add `bg-dark` class to `<nav>`
3. use this [example](https://medium.com/@tiboprea/build-a-responsive-bootstrap-4-navbar-in-angular-5-without-jquery-c59ad35b007) to demo bootstrap behavior in angular

[See here working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-bootstrap-navbar?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-2">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" (click)="isShown = !isShown" >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="collapse justify-content-end navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{ 'show': isShown }" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" (click)="isShown = false" >Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" (click)="isShown = false" >About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" (click)="isShown = false" >Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" (click)="isShown = false" >Book Me</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**TS**

```
isShown:boolean=false;
```

Comment: Thank you! This works so far. But can I change the hamburger without using bg-dark, since a black background is not what I'm looking for. I rather want the hamburger in black with a transparent nav background.

Comment: so remove `navbar-dark bg-dark `

Comment: How can I change the hamburgers color since I assume it's white on white now?

Comment: see here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#color-schemes

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me with the animation? Right now the mobile nav just pops in on click. Can i somehow let it fade in from the top?