# My Bootstrap CSS link doesn't work for me?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the Bootstrap link which usually goes into the HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

It makes my navbar looks like:

(I need at least 10 reputation to post images, so I have to post the direct link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyDtS.png

and after I remove the link:

(I need at least 10 reputation to post images, so I have to post the direct link)
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drrlx.png

But as you can see on the 2 picture, if I dont have the link, the stuff down the navbar ins't in the right position anymore. Please Help.

EDIT:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
      <app-list-employees></app-list-employees>
</div>
  <div class="col-6">
     <div><app-book-employee></app-book-employee></div>
     <p></p>
    <div><app-calendar-books></app-calendar-books></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's the code for the component.

Comment: this the way how to import boostrap to angular:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559810/bootstrap-not-connect-to-the-angular-6/50559906#50559906

Comment: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css try this

Comment: It looks like bootstrap is working fine when you don't use the link, the styling applied to the navbar in the second image is from bootstrap. please provide more HTML, so we can find the problem. You can use https://stackblitz.com/ to create an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the root of your project is the `angular.json` file. 
If you want to use a CDN for bootstrap (like you use now), look for the styles object in this file (probaply between line 25 and 35), in there you can add your link. it should look like this:

```
 "projects": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "styles": [
            "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: what error do you get? can you provide more code so I can have a look?

Comment: I am getting the same tyles like in the picture one. I edited for more code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 6+ in your application it is best advised if you install bootstrap through npm as follows:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

After installing bootstrap add this line in your src/style.css file:

```
@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

This will give you all the bootstrap styles so adding it in your `index.html` file or `angular.json` file is not needed